# Можно ли создать единый метод вызова NSURLConnection для всего приложения?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

IOS приложение (objective-C) имеет несколько разных ViewController, допустим, пять. Каждый обрабатывается своим классом, и в трёх из них отрабатывает одна и та же конструкция запроса данных с сервера:

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

и далее обработка ответа в методах: `- (void)connection:...`

Каким образом можно оптимизировать данную конструкцию, например, чтобы каждый ViewController обращался к отдельному общему классу с методами, где отрабатывалась бы логика запроса данных с сервера и осуществлялся возврат обработанного ответа в класс ViewController?

Comment: Тут много вариантов. например, если вас не интересует весь процесс получения данных, а надо только получить конечный результат, можно энкапсулировать весь процесс в отдельный класс, и написать ему вот такой публичный метод: `-(void)getDataWithURL:(NSURL *request) completion:^(NSData *data)`. соответственно вы ему даете url, он вам дает данные, когда они получены

Comment: Так как `NSURLConnection` класс устарел (deprecated), рекомендую использовать `NSURLSession` в дальнейшем .

Answer (score 2):

Ну конечно можно, более того нужно, можете назвать класс, содержащий сетевые методы, NetworkManager или ServerRequestManager, etc, и вынести в него логику построения запросов. Так же и сами запросы лучше посылать обернув в класс NSOperation и построив очередь для контроля.

Comment: Сделав, например, его синглетоном

Comment: так и не смог реализовать в отдельном классе. Пытался сделать по примеру [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060971/accessing-delegate-of-nsurlsessiontasks-wrapped-in-static-method-in-separate-cla) но имею кучу ошибок, например при описании NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask : Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSData *__strong)...  Возможно, есть у кого пример реализации подобного класса, буду благодарен, если продемонстрируете на Github

Comment: #Pio был бы рад, но рамки данного ресурса - это короткие вопросы и ответы, кроме того, как я вижу Вам нужно пройтись по основам типов данных. NSURLSessionDataTask возвращает один или более объектов NSData. Во может быть пытаетесь ему передать что то не ожидаемое, читайте документацию и туториалы. Вот перевод документации по NSURLSession: http://spec-zone.ru/RU/OSX/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html